# python loop not functioning correctly

Tags: python

```
     `difficulty = ""
     
      while difficulty != "e", difficulty != "m", difficulty != "h":
        difficulty = input("Select your difficulty: [e]asy, [m]edium, [h]ard: ").lower()`
```

This is a snippet from my hangman game. When I type in any of the valid difficulties("e", "m" and "h") it keeps on printing difficulty. Any fixes?

Comment: There is a back tick before "difficulty" on the first line, is that intentional?

Comment: Also is this Python 2 or something? Having commas in the while condition like that is invalid syntax in Python 3.8.

Comment: You can use `and` or `or` in place of commas

Comment: Try `while not difficulty in ('e','m','h')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Samuel Zewdu Here is the correct code you are looking for:

```py
difficulty = ""

while (difficulty != "e") and (difficulty != "m") and (difficulty != "h"):
    difficulty = input(
        "Select your difficulty: [e]asy, [m]edium, [h]ard: ").lower()
    print(difficulty != "e" or difficulty != "m" or difficulty != "h")
print("Loop over.")
```

replace commas with `and` because you want to proceed into while loop only if none of the conditions returns False, which is possible only with `and` operator.

Is this solution working for you?

Comment: @Adin Ackerman No this is in python 3 and I fixed it right after I posted this.